# Select element not displaying Laravel vaildation errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i never had this problem before i have a select element with option and in my controller i set it to required and for some reason the validation error does not display the has error class doesn't even get added to the form-group

html and blade

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('Test') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
       <label for="Return_Type">Return Type <span class="request-alert"></span></label>
         <select name="Test" id="Return_Type" class="form-control">
              <option>Choose One...</option>
                  @foreach($categories as $category)
                     <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                  @endforeach
          </select>
          @if($errors->has('Test'))
             <span class="help-block">
                  {{ $errors->first('Test') }}
             </span>
           @endif
</div>
```

controller

```
 $this->validate($request, [
            'First_Name'    => 'required',
            'Last_Name'     => 'required',
            'Email'         => 'required',
            'Phone'         => 'required',
            'Fax'                        ,
            'Company'                    ,
            'Marketplace'   => 'required',
            'Order_Number'  => 'required',
            'Address_1'     => 'required',
            'Address_2'                  ,
            'City'          => 'required',
            'State'         => 'required',
            'Zip_Code'      => 'required',
            'Test'          => 'required',
            'Product_Name'  => 'required',
            'Quantity'      => 'required',
            'SKU'           => 'required',
        ]);
```

Comment: Do you get errors for the other fields?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah  Sorry i was away for the weekend all the other works except 2 select elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ==> value="" in your first select option, i.e

```
<option value="">Choose One...</option>
```

so change your select form part to

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('Test') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
   <label for="Return_Type">Return Type <span class="request-alert"></span></label>
     <select name="Test" id="Return_Type" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Choose One...</option>
              @foreach($categories as $category)
                 <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
              @endforeach
      </select>
      @if($errors->has('Test'))
         <span class="help-block">
              {{ $errors->first('Test') }}
         </span>
       @endif
```

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

first delete the attributes fax, company and address2 from validate, and add
in the attribute Test  `'Test' => 'required|exists:Test,id'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i tried that already and it didn't work ): i leave those empty because i might need it in the future

Comment: add `'Test' => 'required|exists:Test,id'` in the attribute Test

Comment: it gives me a database issue its looking for a table called Test

Comment: delete id only write `'Test' => 'required|exists:Test'`

Comment: it's still looking for a table called Test

Comment: deleting  fax,company and address2 and using `'Test' => 'required'` what is the error ?

Comment: no error the has-error class didn't get added to the form-group if I leave it blank a submit the for it redirects be back the required rule is work the class and the error text is not showing

Comment: Try `$this->validator($request->all())->validate();`

Comment: I made sure to import use Validator; but i get this error Method [validator] does not exist.